# Overiding onFinishInflate() method

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I am inflating a xml using `LayoutInflater` as I want this View multiple times (dynamically).

My ònCreate` Method is as follows:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);
                    v[i]= new View[4];
            LinearLayout linear= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            for(int i = 1; i <4; i++) {

             v[i]= inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, linear);                         //v[i] returns view i.e. Linear Layout from my row.xml 
            }   
        }
```

my code for row.xml is as follows-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffaf04"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1inInflatedRow"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image_holder" >
        </ImageView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1inInflatedRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@layout/button_selector"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2inInflatedRow"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image_holder" >
        </ImageView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2inInflatedRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@layout/button_selector"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the row contains Buttons and I want to set an onclick listener for buttons i.e. for `button1inInflatedRow` and  `button2inInflatedRow` hich perform same function , but I need to know which button has called the function. So, How do I call `findVieById()` for these buttons? or is there any other way for calling the button `onclick`.. ?

Comment: *I ant to set Onclicklistener for buttons.* - after you inflate the layout find thew buttons in the newly inflated layout and assign the listener. *I knew that listener has to be in View.OnFinishInflate() method.* - maybe if you make your own custom view.

Comment: As you state in your question OnFinishInflate is a view method not an activity one, so you cannot override it in your activity.

Comment: @Christos so where to override method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way (as per my knowledge) to inflate a row is as follows-

```
 View v[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
    linear.addView(v[i]);
```

This v returns the inflated view in row.xml. hence we can access Button as

```
photoButton[i]=(Button) v[i].findViewById(R.id.button1inInflatedRow);
```

Where I was wrong---
I was using

```
View v[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, linear);
```

this V[i] is the parent layout an hence i couldnt access button through

`(Button) v[i].findViewById(R.id.button1inInflatedRow)`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `onFinishInflate()`. Calls to `inflate()` return the newly created view. Just use `findViewById()` on the view with the ids of the buttons one by one and set the OnClickListener on each.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.home);
            LinearLayout linear= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            for(int i = 1; i <4; i++) {

                inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, linear);
            }

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it your layout `R.layout.row` contains `Buttons`, and you want to add `OnClickListeners` to these `Buttons`. You don't need to override any method to do that. The method `inflate()` of the `LayoutInflater` returns the instance of the `View` you just inflated. You can then use `findViewById()` to get the `Buttons` in the layout. Try something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, linear);
Button buttonOne = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()...
```

Comment: v.findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);  that returns LinearLayout .. How could I find button inside LinearLayout>>LinearLayout>>Button.

Comment: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
linear.addView(v);
This worked for me..This way is much easier to inflate a view.

Answer (score 0):

To precisely answer your question which is:

> So, How and Where To Override this method?

The answer is inside a View or ViewGroup subclass.

However it is clear that you are asking how to apply listeners for your buttons in a "row" layout which is "repeated" inside a LinearLayout. There is no need to override this method in order to achieve this but there are some things that need to be cleared for a better answer. For example how many are the buttons in the "row" layout? Do you want each button in each row to do the same thing (call the same function) or the function of the buttons has to be different, let's say based in which row they are?

I will give you a general idea on how to do that but it is based solely on my thinking, if you need a better answer you should edit your question and provide more details like your xml files and what exactly you are trying to do.

Now to the code.

In your "row" xml layout provide the following attribute inside your Button element:

```
android:onClick="ButtonClickFunction"
```

Then in your activity declare a function like this:

```
public void ButtonClickFunction(View v) {
    <Your code here>
}
```

Now whenever this button is clicked (in any row) ButtonClickFunction will be called with the button as the parameter. However this is may not be the best approach if you want for example different actions based on the row number.

Of course you can change "ButtonClickFunction" name with whatever you want. You can read more about my suggestion [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners) and [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick)

Hope this helps...

Comment: You can create two different onClick attributes, one for each button, with two different functions, for example android:onClick="button1inInflatedRowClick" and android:onClick="button2inInflatedRowClick" in the row xml and then in your activity you create two public functions like public void button1inInflatedRowClick(View v) and public void button2inInflatedRowClick(View v). This way each function will be called from each button and you don't need the getViewById at all.